# Understanding Basic Prototyping & Updating Key/Value pairs

Tags: javascript, prototype

First time poster, long time lurker.

I'm trying to learn some more advanced features of .js, and have two ojectives based on the pasted code below:

1. I would like to add methods to a parent class in a specific way (by invoking prototype).
2. I intend to update the declared key/value pairs each time I make an associated method call. execMTAction as seen in TheSuper will execute each function call, regardless. This is by design.

Here is the code:

```
function TheSuper(){ 

this.options = {componentType: "UITabBar", componentName: "Visual Browser", componentMethod: "select", componentValue: null}; 
execMTAction(this.options.componentType, this.options.componentName, this.options.componentMethod, this.options.componentValue); 

}; 

TheSuper.prototype.tapUITextView = function(val1, val2){ 

this.options = {componentType: "UITextView", componentName: val1, componentMethod: "entertext", componentValue: val2}; 
};
```

I would like to execute something like this (very simple):

```
theSuper.executeMTAction(); 
theSuper.tapUITextView("a", "b");
```

Unfortunately I am unable to overwrite the "this.options" in the parent, and the .tapUITextView method throws an error saying it cannot find executeMTAction.

All I want to do, like I said, is to update the parameters in the parent, then have executeMTAction run each time I make any method call. That's it. Any thoughts? I understand this is basic but I'm coming from a long-time procedural career and .js seems to have this weird confluence of oo/procedural that I'm having a bit of difficulty with.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: what is executeMTAction?

Comment: This is a specific call to a separate function I use to build an execution string for my mobile automation tool. I pass in the type of ui element, method, etc, and execMTAction handles interacting with the object and doing various verification checks.

Comment: In a separate .lib I am using. That .lib is included in the full script I took this snippet from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of doing this...

```
TheSuper.prototype.tapUITextView = function(val1, val2){ 

this.options = {componentType: "UITextView", componentName: val1, componentMethod: "entertext", componentValue: val2}; 
};
```

you could possibly update the values of the object instead of trying to overwrite it...

```
this.options['componentType'] = "UITextView";
this.options['componentName'] = val1;
this.options['componentMethod'] = "entertext"; // etc...
```

i don't see where you've defined 'executeMTAction()'. i think you could define 'executeMTAction' in TheSuper and execute it from your methods w/ 'this'

```
function TheSuper() {
    this.executeMTAction = function(options) {
        // define...
    }
}
TheSuper.prototype.amethodname = function(options) {
    this.execMTAction(options);
}
```

you could also pass a function as a parameter when making the method call and use it as a callback...

```
TheSuper.prototype.amethodname = function(options, callback) {
    callback(options);
}

theSuper.amethodname(options, execMTAction);
```

sorry it's been a LONG week for me. i may have completely missed what you were asking for. hope it helps some.

Comment: This was so insightful to me! Thank you for this reply. I'm still thinking about implementing some callback structure, but already refactored my code in this fashion and it's running perfectly.